# Badly formatted dates

Tags: excel, date, google-sheets, formatting

Someone sends me a report on Google Sheets with a column of bad dates every month. Every month I struggle to make them consistent. The whole table has hundreds of rows, so doing it manually is a big ball ache. I want DD/MM/YYYY on an Excel sheet.

I have tried downloading to Excel, copying and pasting, and text to columns, and still haven't found a quick solution.

6/20/2023

6/27/2023

6/5/2023

6/24/2023

6/28/2023

6/6/2023

6/22/2023

6/5/2023

6/29/2023

6/12/2023

Comment: Select the whole range and goto `Data` Tab --> use `Text To Columns` --> `First Step` --> Click on `Delimited` --> `Second Step` --> `Do nothing` --> `Third Step` --> Click on `Date` and change to `MDY` --> Click `Finish`. Next format the ranges as date as per your preferred format. In Excel .

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried this and it doesn't work.

Comment: What does it show when you select the range and press `CTRL SHIFT ~` does it change to a number or does it remain unchanged?

Comment: You can try for yourself if you copy the list into Excel. The ones with a middle figure lower than 13 are incorrectly recognised by Excel, and the rest are not recognised as dates at all. For example, 6/5/2023 comes out as 6th May, and 6/29/2023 is not recognised as a date at all. All the dates in the list above are meant to be in June.

Comment: I just tried and Text To Columns just worked on my end, by copying the dates mentioned in the post. Please check again

Comment: Doesn't work for me - Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2306 Build 16.0.16529.20164) 64-bit

Comment: If it's a Google Sheet, have you checked whether it's set to some other locale in File|Settings (like US maybe)? If so, you should be able to change the locale to the one you want (e.g. UK) and get the dates in the correct format.

Comment: Please dont change the tag @BigBen SIr has already edited the same as Google Sheets and the solution provided which you have accepted wihtin seconds of time it is posted is also referring for Google sheets. We have edited the tag as Google sheets please dont keep on changing it again

Comment: @TomSharpe Sir i am not saying to you i am referring to OP

Comment: @Mayukh Bhattacharya
  Understood! BTW I tried the method in my comment and it should work but the dates may need re-formatting as dates before you can import them. The accepted answer might be more convenient though if it avoids the intermediate step.

Comment: But I specified in the question that I would like the solution to be in Excel. What's wrong with having the Excel tag on it?

Comment: No i dont think the solution posted works with Excel. Because there is no such function with `REGEXEXTRACT()` in Excel, it is present in Google Sheets. and both the platforms are different.

Comment: But the subject of the question was both Google Sheets and Excel, and someone may wish to post an answer for Excel, which I and maybe others will find useful. So I will add the tag again. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to work with a helper column (and then copy/paste-values if needed) that works with it as a text and converts it to date:

```
=LET(tx,TO_TEXT(A1),
DATE(REGEXEXTRACT(tx,"/.+/(\d*)"),REGEXEXTRACT(tx,"(\d*)/"),REGEXEXTRACT(tx,".*/(.*)/")))
```

And as an array:

```
=MAP(A1:A,LAMBDA(each,IF(each="","",
LET(tx,TO_TEXT(each),
DATE(REGEXEXTRACT(tx,"/.+/(\d*)"),REGEXEXTRACT(tx,"(\d*)/"),REGEXEXTRACT(tx,".*/(.*)/"))))))
```

[image]